# Why wasn't cron designed like a regular CLI tool?

Tags: cron

`crontab` feels awkward to use. Why does using it involve opening an *inline text editor* of all things, instead of something like:

```
crontab new -name mytask -freq * * * * * -command echo "Hello, World!"

crontab remove -name mytask
```

It seems likely that any `cron` user will want to create `cron` jobs programmatically at some point, which is also made [more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job) by `crontab`'s design; all the solutions on that page smell like workarounds for badly designed behaviour.

Compare that to Windows where I can schedule a task like so:

```
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "mytask"
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem that is not solved with `crontab -l > filename` and `crontab filename`? What is the question here?

Comment: Both those involve reading and writing the entire contents of the crontab to a file; I'm asking why `crontab` doesnt't have a higher-level CLI for adding, viewing, and removing `cron` jobs like CLI tools typically do. For example, I don't read/write the entire property list when I use `xinput`, I just do `xinput set-prop <device> <prop> <value>` I don't have a specific problem, I'm asking why a design decision might have been made, which I think is an acceptable question.

Comment: Does it matter _why_ it was made like that? You seem to be of the opinion that you don't like it, but would that change if you knew the reason it was made like that? Or would it be better to just try to come up with tools that make it work better for you, whatever the original reasons? Anyway, Wikipedia puts the origin of `cron` in Version 7 Unix, from 1979, so the reason might even "because that's the way they came up with first, and it stuck"

Comment: Note that it's not exactly difficult to build wrappers on top of `crontab` to provide functions like `mycrontab add foo '* * * * * some command here'`  or `mycrontab del foo`.

Comment: Indeed. If [that was your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706654/why-wasnt-cron-designed-like-a-regular-cli-tool#comment1337459_706654) I suspect you'd have some first-cut suggestions quite quickly

Comment: Another thing I thought not long after the previous comments: It makes `cron` itself simpler this way, as it only needs to read a file, not edit it. In a time of smaller computers, that may (or may not) have mattered, and there's no need for `cron` to be able to do that, since there already are other tools that can.

Comment: One way to make editing a bit simpler would be to put each rule in a file of its own, but I'm not sure if lots of small files has been an issue for systems in the past. Also it'd require more system calls to scan through all the files, instead of just one. (You need to list the directory too, to see if any new files have appeared, etc.) With one file, it's enough to cache the contents and check the timestamp to see if the file needs to be re-read. But using multiple files is exactly the way I'd go with for creating those wrappers.